# Page number of a founded text

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, office-interop

There are multiple example for finding and replacing a text in a word document (.docx , .doc), but how to find the page that the founded text is located?

Thank you,
Mohsen

Comment: I found this link here that might help you: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/Visual_Basic.NET/Q_27398318.html

Comment: Thank you. But I do not have a credit card. :-)

Comment: @Mohsen: You can find this page through Google, then it's free. Use title as a keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Information(Word.WdInformation.wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)` method on the result of your `Find()` and cast it to an `int` to get the PageNumber where the text was found.

Post your code and I will update it to return the page number.

Here's an example:

```
currentPageNumber = word.ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.Range.Information(
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdInformation.wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
```

Here's the [MSDN documentation on the enumerator used](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdinformation(v=office.15).aspx) to get the PageNumber. Depending on your needs, you may want to use 1 of the 2 enumerators related to PageNumbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void FindLoop()
    {
        Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();

        wordApp.Visible = false;
        object missing = System.Type.Missing;
        object saveChanges = Word.WdSaveOptions.wdSaveChanges;

        Word.Documents docs = wordApp.Documents;

        docs.Open(filePathAndName, ReadOnly: true);

        int intFound = 0;
        Word.Range rng = wordApp.ActiveDocument.Content;   // this = wordApp.ActiveDocument

        rng.Find.ClearFormatting();
        rng.Find.Forward = true;
        rng.Find.Text = this.textBoxSearch.Text.Trim();

        try
        { 
            rng.Find.Execute(
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

            while (rng.Find.Found)
            {
                intFound++;
                rng.Find.Execute(
                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

            }

            MessageBox.Show("Strings found: " + intFound.ToString());

            wordApp.ActiveDocument.Close(saveChanges, ref missing, ref missing);
        }

        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());

            wordApp.ActiveDocument.Close(saveChanges, ref missing, ref missing);
            //wordApp.Application.Quit(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
        }
    }
```